# How can I find out exactly which rule is applying syntax highlighting to a particular code element in VS2022 with Resharper?

Tags: resharper, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2022

I'm running Visual Studio 2022 with Resharper (EAP) and the "Cyberpunk" theme from the VS marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=T0uchM3.CTVS19)

Something is applying a white background to the syntax highlighting, but only on strings in JavaScript code which contain jQuery/CSS selectors - see this example:

[image: a screenshot of JavaScript code in Visual Studio 2022 showing some problems with syntax highlighting]

Regular strings (e.g. the `"click"` in event handler declarations) are fine. I've been through the VS color list looking for anything with a white background but haven't found out where this is coming from.

Any way to highlight a code snippet and see what rules/plugins are applying syntax highlighting to that specific code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

The specific setting here is **Resharper Injected Language Background** in Visual Studio Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors:[image]

(Thank you [@buhakmeh](https://twitter.com/buhakmeh/status/1468302717483376647) for figuring this one out!)